# IE not loading CSS sheet, HTML5 and html5shiv not helping

Tags: css, html, html5shiv

Im working on this html5 , using css, and my website works fine on chrome and firefox, but not in IE 10. Nothing written on css file applies on IE.

My website still remains locally and unfinished,but its driving me crazy as i tried so many answers to fix IE like html5shiv,  and so on...

I checked on the validator also, and i only get errors of not recognized bootstrap attributes.

i would love if someone can get a look on my code

```css
body {
  background-color: #D1E0B2;
}
header,
section,
footer,
aside,
nav,
main,
article,
figure {
  display: block;
}
.fotos {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tres-colunas {
  display: block;
  width: 360px;
  height: 170px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #929493;
  border-top: 1px dashed #929493;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  float: left;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.button-home {
  float: right;
  background-color: #A2BF4D;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #C2E066;
}
.button-home:hover {
  float: right;
  background-color: #9BB352;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #C2E066;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>



  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt" />
  <meta name="description" content=' - ' />
  <meta name="keywords" content=', ' />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />

  <title>Yeshiva Or Israel College</title>
  <script>
    document.createElement("myHero")
  </script>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css" />

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a>
      <img src="tres_rgb.jpg" alt="Logo Da Yeshiva" width="1130" height="145" />
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nossa filosofia</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Os Rabinos</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Campus</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Arquivos
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Fotos</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Textos</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Links Associados
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Camp Hashivenu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Site Rav Karaguilla</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Canal do Rav Passy</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Fa&ccedil;a Parte</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <p> <b> Yeshiv&#225; Or Israel College. </b><i> Educando com amor.</i>
    </p>


    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="carrosel_danca.jpg" alt="Dan&ccedil;a dos Bachurim" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Uni&atilde;o</h3>
            <p>Alunos da Yeshiv&#225; dan&ccedil;ando no p&#225;teo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="carrosel_shabat.jpg" alt="Um Shabat Especial" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Um Shabat Especial</h3>
            <p>A experiencia de Shabatot na Yeshiv&#225; eh algo especial.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="carrosel_havdala_rs.jpg" alt="Havdala" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Alegria no Judaismo</h3>
            <p>Momentos especiais e inesqueciveis</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="carrosel_estudo_fora.JPG" alt="Estudo ao ar livre" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Estudo da Tor&#225;</h3>
            <p>Estudo da Tor&#225; em alto nivel.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="tres-colunas">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <img src="revista.png" alt="Revista Chai Or Israel" width="100" height="150" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
        <h3> Revista Chai </h3>
        <p>A cada ano s&atilde;o lan&ccedil;adas novas revistas da Yeshiv&#225; ricas em conteudo e qualidade. Clique aqui para assinar a sua:</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button-home">Assinar</button>

    </div>
    <div class="tres-colunas">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <img src="calendario.png" alt="calendario" width="100" height="150" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
        <h3> Novidades por aqui </h3>
        <p>Fique por dentro dos novos eventos e acontecimentos.</p>
        <span style="padding:25px"> </span>
      </div>
      <button class="button-home">Confira</button>

    </div>
    <div class="tres-colunas">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <img src="livro-dessler.jpg" alt="Livros da Yeshiv&#225;" width="100" height="150" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
        <h3> Livros da Yeshiv&#225; </h3>
        <p>A Yeshiv&#225; j&#225; publicou dezenas de livros. Venha conhecer quais!</p>
        <span style="padding:25px"> </span>
      </div>
      <button class="button-home">De uma olhada</button>

    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

, im not loading the images, if its necessary tell me...

Comment: Which stylesheet causes problems ? The Bootstrap one or yours ?

If yours, is the stylesheet in the same folder than your html ?

Also, you've written a condition which will apply to browsers lower than IE9, and you said you're trying to make it work on IE10

Comment: My stylesheet. yes, its in the same folder. i tried also to put the condition to IE10, didnt help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the same thing on server cause respond.js works only on server.

Comment: Thats the right answer for me. It wont open right using the browser IE locally, but it would work on server. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

check if other browser are showing it correctly or not like(chrome ,firefox etc) also check if this happens only in your laptop/pc or every laptop/pc.

if it is happening only in your pc/laptop then there might be a chance that your IE has not enabled the style sheet option. I also had the same problem.
To fix this issue use the following steps:--

1.Start regedit.exe.

2.Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main.

3.Double-click Use StyleSheets (or create this value of type String if it doesn't exist).

4.To allow style sheets, set StyleSheets to yes; to disallow, set it to no.
Click OK.

5.Close regedit.

6.Restart Internet Explorer (IE).

do reply if this help you or not..

Comment: Thank You. I tried your answer, created a StyleSheets string as you said and set to yes. Didnt help. And yes, it does work on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: i also had this problem and that worked for me ..  ok try this one at below

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 8.1 using IE11 with the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

On your computer search for "regedit.exe" (go to the start menu and click on the search button on the top-right corner of the screen).

Once regedit opens up, on the left column click on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" and then on ".css"On the right column double-click on "Content Type". This will open up a dialog box.

In the dialog box change "value data" to "text/css".

Click "Ok" and that's it.

I hope this helps other people out there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers.... in my case content type was already set to text/css.... still with the problem, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try loading the style sheet first by typing the below link in the address bar
    http://localhost:paortnumber/path of your css folder/myStyle.css

Please let me know what you find?

Comment: are you sure its paort? Maybe im doing it wrong... if my folder is in C:/Users/MyName/site/myStyle.css i have to write all of this instead of "path"?

Comment: ERR_CONECTION_REFUSED.  maybe the portnumber its not 8080?

Comment: try 80 instead of 8080